# open target _blank window with specific size with Mootools

Tags: html, mootools

how can I resize a window which is opened by a link with target_blank with Mootools?

Thank you

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hxyTB/5/

```
<a href="http://www.golivewire.com/forums/img.cgi?i=168078" target="_blank">klick</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The script/function is plain javascript and I added the event handler with Mootools ( the click event handler you have on your fiddle looks like jQuery to me). Check the function's parameters and change as you need.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KgApM/1/)

```
document.getElements('a.window').addEvent('click',function(e){
    e.stop();
    NewWindow(this.href,'pagename','350','500','no','center');
    return false
});

var win = null;
function NewWindow(mypage, myname, w, h, scroll, pos) {
    if (pos == "center") {
        LeftPosition = (screen.width) ? (screen.width - w) / 2 : 350;
        TopPosition = (screen.height) ? (screen.height - h) / 2 : 500;
    } else {
        LeftPosition = 0;
        TopPosition = 20
    }
    settings = 'width=' + w + ',height=' + h + ',top=' + TopPosition + ',left=' + LeftPosition + ',scrollbars=' + scroll + ',location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no';
    win = window.open(mypage, myname, settings);
}
```

- You can read more about [**window.open() at MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open) to adjust details. In the code above for example there is no url bar, and no scroll bar.
- I used Mootools's `.getElements()`, this will work for other `<a>` with same class. If you have just one element you can use Mootools's `.getElement()`, without "s".

Comment: That is far more code than I would have expected. I will dig my way through it, thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: @RockScientist, you can have less code. The `window.open()` part is the most important, you could remove the whole if/else thing and just give it a position and with/height. But like this you can see the different options.

Comment: @RockScientist, an example of a shorter version, less customised - http://jsfiddle.net/KgApM/2/